# Is $\operatorname{PL}_{n,n-1}$ contractible?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smoothing-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\PL{PL}$Consider the group $\PL_{n,n-1}$ of orientation preserving PL self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$ that also preserve $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ pointwise. It is usually understood as a simplicial group whose $k$-simplices are PL self-homeomorphisms $\mathbb R^n\times\Delta^k\to \mathbb R^n\times \Delta^k$ commuting with the projection on $\Delta^k$. Is this simplicial group contractible?

Comment: To compare $Top_{n,n-1}$ is contractible being isomorphic to $Homeo_\partial(D^n)^{\times 2}$, the latter being contractible by the Alexander trick.

Comment: Why can you not use the PL Alexander trick as well? But I am not even sure the Alexander trick is what you want in any case because this result is true for Diff as well.

Comment: The problem is that a PL self-homeomorfism of $R^n$ induces a non-PL self-homeomorphism of $S^n=R^n\cup\infty$.

Comment: I suppose what you actually want is the punctured Alexander trick which is that $\operatorname{CAT}_\partial(D^n - \{0\})$ is contractible. That is true because it is just the Alexander trick but without the origin.

Comment: You are right. Thank you! Explicitly, $$H(x,y,t)=\begin{cases}(x,y),&|y|\leq t;\\ f(x,y-sign(y)t)+(0,sign(y)t).&|y|\geq t.\end{cases}$$

Comment: $x\in R^{n-1}$, $y\in R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, see the discussion above with [Connor Malin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/134512/connor-malin).